# Change `standard-indent` for 1 specific major mode

Tags: init-file, indentation, web-mode

I author web apps with the `web-mode` in GNU Emacs, and I use 2 spaces for indentation.

After I examined the `web-mode` source, I found out that the mode defaults to the `standard-indent` variable, which in turn defaults to `4`; and if `standard-indent` is unset, `web-mode` defaults to `2`. I'm not sure if I got the terminology correct, and I guess some older versions of Emacs didn't set the variable, so I got 2-space indent out of the box.

Excerpt from `web-mode.el`:

```lisp
(defcustom web-mode-css-indent-offset
  (if (and (boundp 'standard-indent) standard-indent) standard-indent 2)
  "CSS indentation level."
  :type 'integer
  :safe #'integerp
  :group 'web-mode)
```

Obviously, the custom variables' defaults are set during load.

How can I set `standard-indent` to `2` while `web-mode` loads? Given the way `web-mode` initializes its costomization variables, I think it has to be done while the mode is being loaded into Emacs, and not when I enter the major mode. How do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

```
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq standard-indent 2)))
```

99% of all modes define at least one hook variable. Hook variables just hold a list of functions that will be called in the case of some event, usually upon entering some specific mode. Any time you want something to happen when a mode is activated, you want to add it to a hook function.

Edit: Yes, you're right. Just change the `web-mode-css-indent-offset` variable instead:

```
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)))
```

Incidentally, since the `web-mode-css-indent-offset` has a name starting with `web-mode`, you can be fairly certain that no other mode is going to care what value it has. So you could just customize it. Type `M-x customize-variable web-mode-css-indent-offset` and it'll give you a UI that tells you all the help information about the variable, as well as letting you edit the and save the value for the variable.

Comment: `standard-indent` isn't automatically buffer-local, so you want to `setq-local`.  I would also use a named function -- lambdas in hook variables aren't a good idea IMHO.

Comment: Didn't work, I updated the question.